# How can I convert this type of Excel XLS sheet into proper XML?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, schema

I'm trying to setup a Schema file for use with Excel XML Mapping.  What I want to accomplish is to take each row in my spreadsheet, and have it output XML like this:

Excel Rows:

```
XML_Name   |    Initiative    |    HitPoints
ad_wasp         5                  42
hob_goblin      7                  22
```

Desired XML Output:

```
<entities>
 <ad_wasp>
     <initiative>5</initiative>
     <hitpoints>42</hitpoints>
 </ad_wasp>
 <hob_gob>
     <initiative>7</initiative>
     <hitpoints>22</hitpoints>
 </hob_gob>
</entities>
```

In other words - I want to make the first row in my Excel sheet a main element tag, and then under that, put the following rows in as sub-elements.  I want it in this format as a program I'm working with (Fantasy Grounds 2) accepts modular addons in XML format, and needs uniquely named elements like this, enclosing sub-elements.

Keep in mind - I'm totally new to XML.  Maybe I can't do this.  What I've been able to pick up in the last 3 hours is ...

1. In Excel, click into the Developer tab.
2. Define an XML Map Source
3. Point it to the XSD

I've created a schema file as you can see below using XMLSpy - BUT, the problem I'm having is that the schema below puts everything in tags like this:

```
<xml_tag>
    <Name>aasimar</Name>
    <XP>Aasimar</XP>
    <CR>Aasimar</CR>
    <Init>Aasimar</Init>
</xml_tag>
```

Is there a way to do what I want?  If I try to put a "type="xs:string"" declaration into the "XML_Tag" element, I get an error (The 'type' attribute and an anonymous type definition are mutually exclusive for element declaration 'xml_tag'.)  However - I don't know how to make the element a "dynamic variable" (probably the wrong jargon to use), as opposed to the same, static tag.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Entities">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="xml_tag" form="unqualified" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" form="unqualified" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="XP" type="xs:integer" form="unqualified" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="CR" type="xs:integer" form="unqualified" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="Init" type="xs:integer" form="unqualified" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```